# Create sequence number in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Input XML:

```
<doc>
 <section>
  <para>Paragraph 1</para>
  <para>Paragraph 2</para>
  <para>Paragraph 3</para>
 </section>
  <para>Paragraph 4</para>
  <para>Paragraph 5</para>
  <para>Paragraph 6</para>
</doc>
```

Required output:

```
<book>
<section>
  <p class="para" id="0001">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="para" id="0002">Paragraph 2</p>
  <p class="para" id="0003">Paragraph 3</p>
 </section>
  <p class="para" id="0004">Paragraph 4</p>
  <p class="para" id="0005">Paragraph 5</p>
  <p class="para" id="0006">Paragraph 6</p>
 </book>
```

I tried with following XSL but I am not getting desired output. Anyone could help me in this?

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
    <p class="para" id="{$count}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

The result I am getting is:

```
<p class="para" id="2">Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="para" id="4">Paragraph 2</p>
<p class="para" id="6">Paragraph 3</p>

    <p class="para" id="4">Paragraph 4</p>
    <p class="para" id="6">Paragraph 5</p>
    <p class="para" id="8">Paragraph 6</p>
```

Comment: are you getting this ? <p class="para" id="4">Paragraph 4</p>

Comment: No, the result I am getting is:     `<p class="para" id="2">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p class="para" id="4">Paragraph 2</p>
    <p class="para" id="6">Paragraph 3</p>
     
        <p class="para" id="4">Paragraph 4</p>
        <p class="para" id="6">Paragraph 5</p>
        <p class="para" id="8">Paragraph 6</p>`

Comment: Please show your output XML ***by editing your question***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an option that isn't using `xsl:for-each` or any `xsl:variable`'s...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <section>
        <para>Paragraph 1</para>
        <para>Paragraph 2</para>
        <para>Paragraph 3</para>
    </section>
    <para>Paragraph 4</para>
    <para>Paragraph 5</para>
    <para>Paragraph 6</para>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <book>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p class="para" id="{format-number(count(preceding::para)+1,'0000')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<book>
   <section>
      <p class="para" id="0001">Paragraph 1</p>
      <p class="para" id="0002">Paragraph 2</p>
      <p class="para" id="0003">Paragraph 3</p>
   </section>
   <p class="para" id="0004">Paragraph 4</p>
   <p class="para" id="0005">Paragraph 5</p>
   <p class="para" id="0006">Paragraph 6</p>
</book>
```

---

A second option is instead of counting `preceding::para` you could use `xsl:number`...

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <p class="para">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:number format="0000" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i did. if someone downvote against one up, u will get 9 (10-2). :-)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Thank you. Also, I enjoyed your blog posting about word ladders. Very interesting!

Comment: @DevNull, You are always welcome. Apologies for the messed code formatting of the blog post -- at present I haven't found a way to make WordPress format XML/XSLT code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your required xsl

```
 <xsl:template match="doc">
    <book>
        <section>
            <xsl:for-each select="section/para">
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:variable name ="seq">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($count,'0000')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <p class="para" id="{$seq}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </section>
        <xsl:variable name="secCount" select="count(section/para)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="para">
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:variable name ="seq">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number( number($count) + number($secCount),'0000')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
            <p class="para" id="{$seq}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </book>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Experts may still simplify this xsl. I've tried up to my knowledge.

Comment: That won't work too well if there is more than one `section` or if the `section` isn't always before sibling `para`'s.